# 400 Bad Request during Debezium Postgres connector registering

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

After configuring Kafka and debezium connect as mentioned in [this](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/tutorial.html) tutorial, whenever I do:

This is my connector creation.

```sh
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{"name": "postgres-order-debezium-connector","config":{"connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector","database.hostname": "localhost","database.port": "5432","database.user": "postgres","database.password": "postgres","database.server.id": "184054","database.server.name": "postgres-order-service","database.whitelist": "public.order-service","database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "bitnami-kafka-server:9092","database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.order-service"}}'
```

I've got the following response.

```
    {
        "error_code": 400,
        "message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
                    A value is required You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint 
                    /{connectorType}/config/validate"
    }
```

I've run **Zookeeper**, **Kafka**, **Postgres** and **debezium connect** as docker container and the configurations are given below.

**Zookeeper**

```sh
    docker run -d -it -p 2181:2181 --name bitnami-zookeeper --network local-app-tier
            -e ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes 
            bitnami/zookeeper:latest
```

**Apache Kafka**

```sh
    docker run -d -it -p 9092:9092 --name bitnami-kafka-server --network local-app-tier 
            -e ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes 
            -e KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=bitnami-zookeeper:2181 
            bitnami/kafka:latest
```

**Debezium connect (i've tried with version 1.1 as well)**

```sh
    docker run -it -p 8083:8083 --name debezium-postgres-connect --network local-app-tier
        -e GROUP_ID=1
        -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=debe_postgres_configs
        -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=debe_postgres_offsets
        -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=debe_postgres_statuses
        -e BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=bitnami-kafka-server:9092
        --link local-postgres:local-postgres
        debezium/connect:latest
```

**Postgres docker**

```sh
    docker run -it -p 5432:5432 --network local-app-tier --name local-postgres -e
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234 -d postgres
```

*I've tried with debezium postgres image as well*

What I possibly did wrong with my configurations?

Comment: Can you check your Kafka Connect worker log for when you run the `curl`? I think there should be more error details than what you've quoted.

Comment: You probably have a `/logs` directory. Try to check and put some relevant errors from the files.